# change or make animateLayoutChanges faster

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-xml

I am using android:animateLayoutChanges="true" to animate when I change views to VISIBLE or GONE. The default animation for this is cross fade, however its a bit slow and I want it faster or I would like to use a different animation. How is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning in Android 3.0 (API level 11), the Android 2D rendering pipeline supports hardware acceleration, meaning that all drawing operations that are performed on a View's canvas use the GPU. Because of the increased resources required to enable hardware acceleration, your app will consume more RAM.

In your Android manifest file, add the following attribute to the  tag to enable hardware acceleration for your entire application:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

For detailed information about hardware acceleration visit the following link: [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, I will run a test later to see if that activity is hardware accelerated, since I am running API 17, it should be automatic, but this is indeed interesting and might help, thanks.